# How to promote the public beta?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

*I consider the the following two questions outdated. Please consider closing them as duplicates of this one. Their discussion drifted, because tor.stackexchange was still in private beta. Let's start with fresh thoughts how to promote the public beta.*

- *[We need more people coming to the site!](https://tor.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47/we-need-more-people-coming-to-the-site)*
- *[How do we promote our site?](https://tor.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9/how-do-we-promote-our-site)*

**How to promote the public beta?**

Comment: That was quick. You even beat the official announcement :) Also, [this discussion](http://meta.tor.stackexchange.com/q/9/97) is still valid. Only one of the answers is now obsolete.

Comment: Question http://meta.tor.stackexchange.com/questions/9/how-do-we-promote-our-site you are referring to starts with "

Should we just see if anybody i the Tor irc channel wants an invite to the beta (private or public) and does anybody know anybody that would be a great person to have on the site to answer questions?" - not related to public beta.

Comment: Duplicate of [How do we promote our site?](http://meta.tor.stackexchange.com/q/9/58), the discussion mentioned by AsheeshR

Comment: So I've been criticized for pointing here from tor-talk. Perhaps that was imprudent of me, in light of past discussion. Should I stop doing that? In other words, is that not a good way to promote the site?

Answer (score 3):

My ideas :

1.Write an email to Tor Project and ask him to provide a link to our site on his homepage.

2.Tell about Tor, and of course Tor.SE to everyone of our friends, familiy, etc ...

3.Ask Tor Project to make our page a default page in Tor Browser.

4.Have own IRC channel.

5.Let's advertise on a lot of different forums, sites, etc., about Tor or about Tor.SE

6.Give information on Facebook (and create a site for our Q&A !), Google+, Twitter, etc.

7.Write a letter to small newspapers (or maybe big ...) about nour ew Q&A site promoting anonymity in Internet.

Comment: I created a [Trac ticket](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/9887) for item 3 suggesting that we add the Q&A site to the Tor Browser Bundle as a bookmark.

Comment: I also commented on a [GitHub ticket](https://github.com/arlolra/check/issues/19) suggesting that we add a link to the Q&A site on [check.torproject.org](https://check.torproject.org/).

Comment: I created a second [Trac ticket](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/9888) for item 3 suggesting that we add a link on the about:tor page used in the alpha Tor Browser Bundle.